# Jinja2 map list to dictionary

Tags: python, jinja2, salt-stack

Is it possible to convert list of primitives to list of dicts using Jinja2 using list/map comprehensions?

Given this structure:

```
list:
  - some_val
  - some_val_2
```

Apply `map` on every element to obtain:

```
list:
  - statically_added: some_val
  - statically_added: some_val_2
```

It is possible other way around: `list_from_example|map(attribute="statically_added")|list`

Answer (score 3):

I came up with the same question and found this solution:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ mylist | json_query('[].{\"statically_added\": @}') }}"
  vars:
    mylist:
      - some_val
      - some_val_2
```

Output:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "statically_added": "some_val"
        },
        {
            "statically_added": "some_val_2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing my own, tiny filter. I'm using Ansible, but I hope it's possible to adapt it for other environments as well.

For Ansible place this into file `filter_plugins/singleton_dict.py`:

```py
class FilterModule(object):

    def filters(self):
        return {
            'singleton_dict':
                lambda element, key='singleton': {
                    key: element
                }
        }
```

Then `[1, 2]|singleton_dict(key='name')` produces `[{'name': 1}, {'name': 2}]`. When no `key=` is specified, it defaults to `'singleton'`.

Answer (score -1):

It's actually pretty simple. At least, this works in Ansible:

```
vars:
  my_list:
    - some_val
    - some_val_2
  dict_keys:
    - key_1
    - key_2
tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ dict(dict_keys | zip(my_list)) }}"
```

Output:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "key_1": "some_val",
        "key_2": "some_val_2"
    }
```

}

Note that you have to provide a list of keys, and they need to be distinct (the nature of dictionary implies that keys can't be the same).

UPDATE. Just realised that the title was a bit misleading, and I answered the title, not the actual question. However, I'm going to leave it as it is, because I believe many people will google for converting a list into a dictionary and find this post.

Comment: What if the list is dynamic in size, and thus you need to generate dict_keys? (assume each key is the same)

Comment: Since this answer is for Ansible (but that's not the question's target) I'll reply to @Jonathan with what worked for me (assuming a list of string values, no special YAML characters in the list values, etc.) in Ansible:  `input_list | map('regex_replace', '^(.*)$', 'static_key: "\1"') | map('from_yaml') | list`

Comment: This might not be answering the question correctly, but it answered my question that brought me here. Thanks!